# My view automatically goes up when keyboard come in ios

Tags: ios, delegates, keyboard, uitextfield, modalviewcontroller

In my storyboard I have two navigation controllers, say A and B. I bring NavB as a modal controller when a button is clicked on NavA. I have a textfield in my NavB. I have connected this textfield to the controller from storyboard and also have set the textfield delegate. When I click on this textfield, my view automatically animates up. I did some research and found that this happens when I set the delegate for textfield. This dont happen when I push my controller. 
I have no clue how to fix it.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your viewController is `UITableViewContoller`, no?

The autoscroll-behavior is located in the `UITableViewController` functionality. To disable the automatic scrolling there are two ways:

- use instead of the `UITableViewController` simply a `UIViewController` - set the datasource and delegate on your own.
- Override the `viewWillAppear`-Routine - and DON´T call `[super viewWillAppear: animated]`.

Hope this fixes your issue, cheers :)

Comment: No its not UItableviewcontroller :(

Answer (score 0):

I would like to just make sure that your view is not a class of [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tpkeyboardavoiding). Since its description says that:

```
A drop-in universal solution for moving text fields out of the way 
of the keyboard in iOS
```

I have used in the login/sign controllers and observed that when a UITextField goes in edit mode, the TextField goes out of the way and view scrolls accordingly.

Comment: No its not a class of TPKeyboardAvoiding.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. I had unticked 'Under top bars' in the storyboard and thats why i was getting this behaviour.